# ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob'

Tags: python, utf-8, python-import, azure-blob-storage, ansi

I am trying to convert the text files in my Azure blob container from ANSI to UTF-8 encoding without downloading the files locally using python. I am getting the following error when I try to import **BlockBlobService** in my Python code to deal with Azure Blob Storage. I believe I have the correct python modules installed already, but there might be some other module that is missing which I am not aware of or it could be "not having the correct python module version". "pip list" command shows the following on my VM. Any help on this would be good.

> **pip list**
>   Package              Version
>
> ---

```
azure-common         1.1.25
azure-core           1.4.0
azure-nspkg          3.0.2
azure-storage        0.36.0
azure-storage-blob   12.3.0
azure-storage-common 2.1.0
azure-storage-nspkg  3.1.0
bcrypt               3.1.7
certifi              2020.4.5.1
cffi                 1.14.0
chardet              3.0.4
cryptography         2.9
idna                 2.9
isodate              0.6.0
msrest               0.6.13
oauthlib             3.1.0
paramiko             2.7.1
pip                  20.0.2
pycparser            2.20
PyNaCl               1.3.0
python-dateutil      2.8.1
requests             2.23.0
requests-oauthlib    1.3.0
setuptools           41.2.0
six                  1.14.0
urllib3              1.25.8
wheel                0.34.2
```

Comment: `azure-storage-blob   12.3.0` don't use `BlockBlobService `, it uses `BlobServiceClient`. `BlockBlobService ` should be v2 sdk.Check this v12 doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

Comment: it looks like azure-storage-blob 12.3.0 is the latest version                                        Storage - Blobs  pypi  12.3.0  docs 12.3.0    github 12.3.0                              https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/2020-04/python.html

Comment: Yes, just try the sample code in the link it should work.

Comment: I am already using 12.3.0. but getting the error as mentioned in my question

Comment: Check the doc, v12 sdk uses `BlobServiceClient`, if you want to use `BlockBlobService ` should use v2 sdk, refer to this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python-legacy

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to convert the files in the container to UTF-8. I am using the code below but it is not working. create_blob_from_text(container_name, filename, file, encoding ='utf-8'). Please can you help

Comment: I have post my answer, check that. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your blob encoding is not `UTF-8`, it's not able to change it. And you said you want to use `create_blob_from_text` to do it, so I suppose your text file is not `UTF-8` and you want to change it to `UTF-8` to upload it.

Firstly you should know, if your text file is `UTF-8`, you don't need change anything just upload it, it will still be `UTF-8`. However if you file is not `UTF-8`, it won't convert it to `UTF-8`, it will be encoded to `UTF-8` with original encoding. If you could understand this, you will know how to upload you file to azure blob with `UTF-8` encoding.

Like below I upload a text file with encoding `GBK`.

```
txt= open('D:/hello.txt').readline() # GBK Tex

charset = 'UTF-8'
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text(container_name='test',blob_name='test-gbk.txt',text=txt.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('GBK'),encoding=charset)
```

Below is the pic, left is the original file with `GBK` encoding, right is the file downloading from the azure blob it's encoded with 'UTF-8'.

[image]

**Update**: I open the text file to `BytesIO` then upload it with the below code. You could ignore the `latin-1`.

```
text=open('E:/test.txt',encoding='latin-1').readline()
charset = 'UTF-8'
buf=BytesIO(text.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('ANSI').encode('UTF-8'))
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(container_name='test',blob_name='test.txt',stream=buf)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you George for your detailed answer. However, as I have 100 files of 4GB size  each, using create_blob_from_text is taking too long to run. So, I tried                                                                                        blockblob_service.create_blob_from_stream(container_name, file_name, file, count=None, content_settings=ContentSettings(content_encoding='UTF-8')) but it is not converting to UTF-8. It is creating a new blob but with the same encoding as the source which is ANSI. Please can you help.

Comment: Check my updated answer, hope this could help you. If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to do this without downloading the files locally. I followed your steps but I could not find any function to open the file from Blob storage directly. Is there any way to convert to UTF-8 without downloading the files to local system?

Comment: I download to local to check if the encoding is convert to utf-8, the above just upload the file.

Comment: You could not change the blob encoding, only could upload file or stream and convert the encoding type to utf-8. Please check the code.

Comment: Can I not create a new one with new encoding type utf-8 without downloading them. But I guess without opening the file, you can't convert to utf-8 and I could not find a function to open a blob file without downloading

Comment: What about `get_blob_to_stream` or `get_blob_to_text`, this could download blob to stream to text, don't have to store to local then convert encoding and reupload.

Comment: Thank you George for your suggestion. Will it download huge files? I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 12):

Azure-storage-blob, version: 12.3.0 is the latest version which includes BlobServiceClient instead of BlockBlobService, so if you would like to use BlockBlobService, you must specify the azure-storage-blob version to be 2.1.0. just do

```
pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0
```

This would solve your problem.