# How to use AppendBlobService and BlobServiceClient in Python for Azure functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am using AppendBlobService and BlobServiceClient in my Azure function app for two different use cases.

For AppendBlobService I need azure-storage-blob==2.1.0 version and for BlobServiceClient I need azure-storage-blob version < 12.

How can we use both AppendBlobService and BlobServiceClient together in Azure function by avoiding version conflicts.

Comment: Why not use same version of the SDK for both?

Comment: If i use same version, I get the below error. cannot import name 'AppendBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob' .

Comment: Got it. You can probably use [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=storage-py-v12) to do operations on Append Blobs. Have you tried that?

Comment: No , I will try and let you know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**According to [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=environment-variable-windows#upload-blobs-to-a-container) it says,**

> Gets a reference to a  BlobClient  object by calling the  get_blob_clientmethod on the BlobServiceClient from the  Create a container  section.

> So you can use:
> `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient`

***References:***

- [Unable to import AppendBlobService from azure.storage.blob in Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72809831/17623802)
- [ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobService' when using Azure Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46700157)